# what's the work around for virtual functions in a template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to compile this:

```
template <class L>
class A
{
        virtual int doIt() = 0;
};

template <class L>
class B : public A<L>
{
        int doItAgain() { return doIt(); }
};

int main()
{
}
```

and getting the error:

```
3.cc: In member function ‘int B<L>::doItAgain()’:
3.cc:11:32: error: there are no arguments to ‘doIt’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘doIt’ must be available [-fpermissive]
  int doItAgain() { return doIt(); }
                                ^
3.cc:11:32: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

with g++. clang gives an error as well:

```
3.cc:11:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'doIt'
        int doItAgain() { return doIt(); }
                                 ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: `this->doIt();` ... there's a duplicate of this

Comment: ah ha. I found this http://blog.llvm.org/2009/12/dreaded-two-phase-name-lookup.html (just for the record), but it doesn't seem to give a solution. your solution works perfectly. thanks.